# Fat-tailed proposal distribution

Tags: bayesian, fat-tails

I am solving a program using my own MCMC Bayesian code. I block propose my vector by calculating the co-variance using the last 10 000 steps (sampling my posterior).

I want to implement a fat-tailed proposal for the step size, but I want to keep my normally distributed co-variance proposal for the direction. Therefore, I was thinking of drawing a normally distributed X as before, and multiplying it by Y a Cauchy distributed random variable with median 1. Therefore, my proposal is XY.

However, all the literature I've seen about "mixing" distributions or implementing fat-tailed proposals add two variables X+Y where X is normally distributed and Y is some fat tailed distribution.

Why is this? Can I multiply instead?

Comment: Are you doing Hamiltonian Monte Carlo? Why do you have a step size and direction?

Comment: Just regular MC. Sorry, if I was imprecise with the words "step size" and "direction". I meant that I have a vector $x_{o}$ of my current state and, currently, I propose a new vector $x_{prop, Normal}$ by drawing from a multivariate normal distribution with a co-variance matrix. I want to scale the difference $\Delta x = (x_{o}-x_{prop,Normal})$ by the Cauchy distribution and therefore make my new proposal $x_{prop} = x_{o} + Scale*\Delta x$